# What are some colloquial English expressions for comparing hot/cold weather to something else?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, dialects

I'm looking for colloquial expressions that compare hot, cold, and wet weather to something else. For example, “It’s hotter than two goats in a pepper patch”, “Colder than a witch’s tit”, etc. Often these expressions use a superlative formula, such as “Hotter than [X]” or “Cold enough [to do Y]” or “Wet as [Z]”. Some make statements about cause and effect, such as  “It’s so cold [X event could happen]”. I'm especially interested in examples that have widespread or historical usage. Something you’ve heard different people say, or something your grandparents used to say - not something you just made up. This is for an art project, focusing on expressions from the United State and Ireland, in English and Gaelic, but will include expressions from other languages as long as an English translation is included.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help): your question does not easily fit our format, which calls for definitive answers rather than lists of suggestions. I would point out that the two examples you cite are applicable to any temperature, not just the weather— and that is likely true of the vast majority of such expressions.

Comment: Thanks, and good point about the applicability beyond temperature. First-time poster here, I'll try to fit the format next time.

Answer (score 1):

It is 'cold enough to freeze the balls off a brass monkey' (postings *passim*) is the obvious one. This was widely used in Britain in the 20th century but may be going out of fashion.

Comment: Always a fave. Do you know the nautical origins of this one?

Comment: Thanks, that's a classic. And fancy seeing you here, Wes!